# Customising sharepoint navigation - code location help

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, custom-masterpage

I am very new to SharePoint and html/jquery coding. I am trying to follow this video for custom navigation:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rIDnqswlAzw
And am lost on how to save/load the code in SharePoint designer. I get the master page part of the code - just not the code that the master file refers to - do I just create a .css file and point to that in my master file - or should I be doing something else?

It also refers to KnockOut code - do I need to download the knockout.js file and save that so it can be referenced?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For each SharePoint sites there is a library with name "Style Library". You can use this library to store the css style files which you are using in the site.

You can create a new custom css file using any editor (or SharePoint Designer) and then upload it to the Style Library. Then you can add the reference in Master Page.

If you are planning to use JavaScript libraries like jQuery or Knockout then you need to download them separately and upload it to SharePoint libaries.